# nodejs filtering an array of objects where the filtering is partially done in an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, filter, async-await

I've read many similar questions and have tried a bunch of code. Unfortunately, I'm not getting my code to run :-(

So, the situation is as follows: In a route of a node.js server, I have to respond with a filtered array of Objects. Unfortunately, whatever I do, I always get an empty array [] back. The filter is a bit tricky in my opinion, as it consists of a string comparison AND an async call to a library function. With the console output, I can clearly see that the correct element is found, but at the same time I see that I've already received the object...

Here is some code that exemplifies my challenge:

```
let testArray = [
  {
    id: 'stringId1',
    data: {
      someDoc: {
        moreContent: 'Some random content',
        type: 'noInterest'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'stringId2',
    data: {
      someDoc: {
        moreContent: 'Some random content',
        type: 'ofInterest'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'stringId3',
    data: {
      someDoc: {
        moreContent: 'Some random content',
        type: 'ofInterest'
      }
    }
  }
]

// code from a library. Can't take an influence in it.
async function booleanWhenGood(id) {
  if (id in some Object) {
    return { myBoolean: true };
  } else {
    return { myBoolean: false };
  }
}

// Should return only elements with type 'ofInterest' and that the function booleanWhenGood is true
router.get('/', function(res,req) {
  tryOne(testArray).then(tryOneResult =>{
    console.log('tryOneResult', tryOneResult);
  });
  tryTwo(testArray).then(tryTwoResult => {
    console.log("tryTwoResult ", tryTwoResult);
  });

  result = [];
  for (const [idx, item] of testArray.entries() ) {
    console.log(idx);
    if (item.data.someDoc.type === "ofInterest") {
      smt.find(item.id).then(element => {
        if(element.found) {
          result.push(item.id);
          console.log("ID is true: ", item.id);
        }
      });
    }

    if (idx === testArray.length-1) {
      // Always returns []
      console.log(result);
      res.send(result);
    }
  }
})


// A helper function I wrote that I use in the things I've tried
async function myComputeBoolean(inputId, inputBoolean) {
  let result = await booleanWhenGood(inputId)
  
  if (result.myBoolean) {
    console.log("ID is true: ", inputId);
  }

  return (result.myBoolean && inputBoolean);
}

// A few things I've tried so far:
async function tryOne(myArray) {
  let myTmpArray = []

  Promise.all(myArray.filter(item => {
    console.log("item ", item.id);
    myComputeBoolean(item.id, item.data.someDoc.type === "ofInterest")
    .then(myBResult => {
      console.log("boolean result", myBResult)
      if (myBResult) {
        tmpjsdlf.push(item.id);
        return true;
      }
    })
  })).then(returnOfPromise => {
    // Always returns [];
    console.log("returnOfPromise", myTmpArray);
  });

  // Always returns []
  return(myTmpArray);
}

async function tryTwo(myArray) {
  let myTmpArray = [];
  myArray.forEach(item => {
    console.log("item ", item.id);
    myCompuBoolean(item.id, item.data.someDoc.type === "ofInterest")
    .then(myBResult => {
      console.log("boolean result", myBResult)
      if (myBResult) {
        myTmpArray.push(item.did);
      }
    })
  });

  Promise.all(myTmpArray).then(promiseResult => {
    return myTmpArray;
  });
}
```

Asynchronous programming is really tough for me in this situation... Can you help me get it running?

Comment: You already use `async`/`await` - why are you still calling `.then()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't inspect your attempts that closely, but I believe you are experiencing some race conditions (you print return and print the array before the promises resolve).

However you can alwayd use a regular for loop to filter iterables. Like this:

```
let testArray = [
    {
        id: 'stringId1',
        data: {
            someDoc: {
                moreContent: 'Some random content',
                type: 'noInterest'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'stringId2',
        data: {
            someDoc: {
                moreContent: 'Some random content',
                type: 'ofInterest'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'stringId3',
        data: {
            someDoc: {
                moreContent: 'Some random content',
                type: 'ofInterest'
            }
        }
    }
]

async function booleanWhenGood(id) {
    if (id in { 'stringId1': 1, 'stringId2': 1 }) { // mock object
        return { myBoolean: true };
    } else {
        return { myBoolean: false };
    }
}

async function main() {
    let filtered = []
    for (item of testArray)
        if ((await booleanWhenGood(item.id)).myBoolean && item.data.someDoc.type === 'ofInterest')
            filtered.push(item)
    console.log('filtered :>> ', filtered);
}

main()
```

Comment: I actually got it working just 10 minutes ago. I looked again at the problem and used "divide & conquer" to find exactly where the problem was. At the end, I used array.map(), which actually helped me remove code afterwards as well...